# Checking if the string is palindrome or not after removing a character multiple times?

Tags: algorithm

So, I was solving the following problem:

```
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/276/B
```

Now, the logic that I thought of is as follows:

1. Check if the string is already a palindrome.
2. If yes, print First and break.
3. If not, then call remove function.
4. Check if string is already a palindrome.
5. If yes, print second and break
6. Else call remove function.

Continue steps 1-6 until we encounter a particular break statement.

where remove function is as follows:

```
string rm (string s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    int l=0,r=len-1;
    while (l < r)
    {
        if (s[l] != s[r])
        {
            s.erase(l,1);
            //l++;
            //r--;
            break;
        }
        l++;
        r--;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Basically, it looks for the first mismatch in the string from the ending, and removes that character. (since both players play optimally)

Now, I am getting a WA on one of the test cases in which the string is quite long (so long that I cannot write here). I read the editorial and there logic was different than mine, and I understood that. But, I just wanted to know if there is anything wrong in my logic. There might be some error in my code but I just want to know if my logic is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the players can reorder the letters, thus

```
abcdcdba
```

Is already a winning situation (reorder -> `abcddcba`).

Comment: Right. Yes, I didn't consider this.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm wont detect the shortest palindromes consisting of just 1 char.

Answer (score 0):

If there are an odd number of letters that appear an odd number of times in the string, then first player wins. Else, second player wins.

```
string whichPlayerWins(string s) {
    int len = s.length();
    int counts[26] = { [0 ... 25 ] = 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        counts[s[i] - 'a']++;
    int numOdd = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (counts[i] % 2 == 1) numOdd++; 
    }
    if (numOdd % 2 == 1) return "First";
    else return "Second";
}
```

Comment: Right, that was there in the editorial. I understood this. I am just asking if there is something wrong with my solution.

Comment: Your solution is wrong because it doesn't take into account reorderings. I can't see how or why you'd even try to make a solution involving manual Removals and checking for palindrome-icity after each removal? If you understood this, then why would you even try your logic?